# FFMPEG av_read_frame() return an I/O error (-5)?

Tags: c++, service, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg library to capture screen (desktop). Everything works fine when I run my app in debug/release mode. The I/O error comes when this app run in c# window service mode (win 10 OS). I googled but still don't know why the error come. In the service mode there is no problem when connecting to some rtsp link (Camera) except desktop capture.

```
AVInputFormat * pAVInputFormat = av_find_input_format("gdigrab"); 
if (pAVInputFormat != NULL) 
{ 
   int err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "desktop", pAVInputFormat, NULL); 
   if(err== 0) 
   { 
      err = av_read_frame(&pFormatCtx, &packet); 
      if (err < 0) 
      { 
          char errs[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE]; 
          av_make_error_string(errs, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, err ); 
          String^ errStr = gcnew String(errs); 
          WriteLog("Error in function av_read_frame() return = " + errStr); 
          return -1; 
     } 
   } 
}
```

---

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I read that services normally don't have access to the desktop.

Comment: `av_make_error_string(errs, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, err );` must give you what the error is, and I believe -5 is EIO, aka IO Error.